# How do you use both curved and straight voltages in LaTeX with circuitikz package?

Tags: latex, circuit

Currently I am using:

```
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
```

and in the body I have only:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0) to[R = $R_6$, v = $U_{R6}$] (1.5,0)
          to[R = $R_6$, v = $U_{R6}$] (3,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Please do not care about the naming. I just need to have both straight and curved voltage in the same file in LaTeX.

[image: Left: curved voltage; right: straight voltage]

There is the whole code if it helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \section{My header}
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0) to[R = $R_6$, v = $U_{R6}$] (1.5,0)
            to[R = $R_6$, v = $U_{R6}$] (3,0)
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz so I added the whole code but not sure if it actually helps you. As I have said earlier, there isn't much more code except the use of package and block with circuitikz.

Comment: Making a complete example is always a good idea. If nothing else, it makes it easier for the people trying to help you because you have already done all the boring tasks like adding a document class and we can just copy&paste your code and directly start working on your problem.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right, thanks for the tip and help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `voltage=straight` to change the style of individual elements:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \section{My header}
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0) to[R = $R_6$, v = $U_{R6}$] (1.5,0)
            to[R = $R_6$, v = $U_{R6}$, voltage=straight] (3,0)
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem exactly how I wanted.

Comment: @agentt015 You're welcome!